# Overhanging section of part turns into spaghetti

Tags: print-quality, support-structures

[A part](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4195002) I've printed (on a Monoprice Maker Select V2, sliced with Cura) has a small peg on it, which is an unsupported overhanging section of the model.

The first few layers of the peg end up a mess of PLA spaghetti. Here I've rotated the part to get a better shot, normally it would be printed on its side.

[image]

I've done test prints that contain L-shaped overhangs and they worked ok, so I'm not sure what's broken about this one.

One guess I have is that because the peg is relatively low to the heated build plate, the material isn't cooling as quickly, and it needs to be more rigid in order for subsequent layers to print.

I also tried with supports but I found it too hard to remove.

Comment: There are a lot of options in Cura to adjust the density and gapping of supports.  Take a look at those.

Answer (score 2):

Unsupported parts need to be printed with support. If your supports are too hard to remove, try the Tree Support setting and make sure that your support structure is set up with a gap to the actual print. As we don't know which slier you use, I can't go into more details here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try printing slower and/or increase cooling ( possibly even a cooler bed temp) if you absolutely want to avoid supports, or just use supports with a support interface and tweak support distance.